# How to skip first line between two patterns in awk?

Tags: awk

I have the next script

```
cat foo.txt | awk '/ERROR/,/INFO/'
```

With the input of:

```
FooFoo
ERROR
Foo1
INFO
FooFoo
```

Now the result is:

```
ERROR
Foo1
INFO
```

I am looking for the next result:

```
Foo1
INFO
```

How I can make it work?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
awk '/ERROR/,/INFO/' foo.txt | tail -n +2
```

If your input is from a file, you don't need the cat. just `awk '...' file`

Comment: @KobiOrgad and the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/ERROR/{
  found=1
  next
}
found{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
/INFO/{
  print val
  val=count=found=""
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
/ERROR/{                      ##Checking if line contains ERROR then do following.
  found=1                     ##Setting found variable here.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found{                        ##Checking here if found is SET then do following.
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0      ##Creating variable val and keep adding value to it in form of current line.
}
/INFO/{                       ##Checking condition if INFO is found in current line then do following.
  print val                   ##Printing val here.
  val=count=""                ##Nullifying val and count here.
}
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk '
    seen            # a true (1) condition makes awk to print current line
    /ERROR/{seen=1} # if we grep ERROR, assign 1 to seen flag
    /INFO/{seen=0}  # if we grep INFO, assign 0 to seen flag
' file
```

## Output

```
Foo1
INFO
```